# Corona SDK dynamically change sprite speed

Tags: animation, sprite, coronasdk

I am trying to make a sprite dance according to the beat of a song in Corona SDK. So far I have managed to get periodic samples of frequency for the song playing but I can't seem to dynamically change the sprite movement speed so it matches the frequency.Do you have any idea how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create multiple sequences each with its own play time and switch them using 'prepare'.

Like that:

```
sprite.add( spriteSet, "slow", 1, 10, 1000, 0 )
sprite.add( spriteSet, "fast", 1, 10, 500, 0 )

local instance = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet )
instance:prepare("slow")
instance:play()
```

When music gets faster:

```
instance:prepare("fast")
instance:play()
```